# Can't find advanced settings on my SMC router

Tags: router, dns, opendns

Trying to change my SMC router's WAn setting to use opendns dns.

Following the instructions: https://store.opendns.com/setup/device/smc

I don't see advanced settings anywhere, and none of the menu or menu options have WAN and dns relation options.

Could my ISP (who provided the router) blocked that option?

Comment: By curiosity, why using the lying DNS resolvers of OpenDNS ?

Comment: what do you mean lying?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://bitemytonguefornoone.wordpress.com/2008/09/30/change-dns-server-on-rogers-smc-wireless-router/) some instructions on how to do this.

Basically, you need to log in to the router as a special user to change those kinds of settings. This page was written for Roger's Internet users, but I'd assume it would work for people using the same hardware with other Internet companies as well.